# has anyone used oboe.js with standard JSONP APIs?

Tags: json, ajax, streaming, jsonp, oboe.js

As I understand it, Oboe.js "manually" scans the JSON inside large HTTP requests so that partial results can be used before the request is complete.

What I can't tell (yet) is whether this works in a JSONP world. Will it look inside the function wrapper, or does it require "plain old"/ pure JSON result?